# Using mouse hover function to hide and show in the same position

Tags: html, css, mousehover

I have a problem to do the mouse hover function to hide and show in the same position with two pictures. For example, if I hover over the picture, the second picture will stay in the first picture position and the size is the same as the first picture.

Below is my sample coding:

```html
<style>
.preview-image {
  background-size: 0 0;
  width: 100vw;
}
.nopadding {
  padding: 0!important;
} 
.container:hover .preview-image {
  opacity: 1;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100px;
}
.container:hover .txt-container {
  opacity: 0;
}
.txt-container {
  opacity: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}
.btn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 16px 32px;
}
</style>
 <ul class="nopadding">
<div class="container">
    <li class="preview-image" style="background-image:url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTadW0C0MkeampnVW-_sT7bMOemD3roUI5x-w&usqp=CAU);">
      <div class="txt-container">
          <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQXV2n5aZGMr6SoY-thS3xR6bPchCnUu23SiA&usqp=CAU" />
      </div>
    </li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

For example - if no hover, the first picture will show on the page:

[image: img1]

For example - if hover to the first picture, the second picture will overlay with the first page and size maintain the same with the first picture on the page:

[image: img2]

Hope someone can guide me on how to solve it. Thanks.

Comment: While you can get the two images roughly in the same position (see answer from @kenitpatel) the basic images you are using have different aspect ratios, neither of them square. To get one to exactly overwrite the other you may like to find images (or edit the ones you have) which have the same aspect ratios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the one below to control the `display` property of two images.

Also I have made the `txt-container` class to an `inline-block` elemment to make the div fit with the images.

```css
.nopadding {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
.txt-container .image-one {
  display: none;
}
.txt-container .image-two {
  display: block;
}
.txt-container:hover .image-one {
  display: block;
}
.txt-container:hover .image-two {
  display: none;
}

.txt-container {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
}

.btn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 16px 32px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nopadding">
  <div class="container">
    <li class="preview-image">
      <div class="txt-container">
        <img
          class="image-one"
          src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTadW0C0MkeampnVW-_sT7bMOemD3roUI5x-w&usqp=CAU" alt="">
        <img
          class="image-two"
          src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQXV2n5aZGMr6SoY-thS3xR6bPchCnUu23SiA&usqp=CAU" />
      </div>
    </li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please fix your code it should be change when you hover on the image and not on page

Answer (score 3):

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <style>
    .card {
      width: 227px;
      height: 235px;
      background: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQXV2n5aZGMr6SoY-thS3xR6bPchCnUu23SiA&usqp=CAU") no-repeat;
      margin: 50px;
    }
    
    .card:hover {
      background: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTadW0C0MkeampnVW-_sT7bMOemD3roUI5x-w&usqp=CAU") no-repeat;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="card"></div>
</body>

</html>
```